# Set container layout above BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout. This layout contains BottomNavigationView and container for nested fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="client.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I set `app_bar_main` above BottomNavigationView top?

because now:

[image]
BottomNavigationView cross with

Comment: what do you mean cross with?

Comment: app_bar_main  is drawn to the bottom of the screen. but it is necessary to the top BottomNavigationView

Comment: in the picture you provided, the app_bar_main is on top of the BottomNavigationView; is that not the case?

Comment: I'm not an artist))). green dots I show that app_bar_main  cross with BottomNavigationView

Comment: I see. instead of constraining your BottomNavigationView to parent, try giving the app_bar_main layout an ID and constrain BottomNavigationView to the bottom of that ID instead?

Comment: I eddiet questions. in app_bar_main  fragment with button on the bottom. I wait button(bottom of fragment) above BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 5):

I have used a `FrameLayout` to prevent the `BottomNavigationView` from overlapping with layouts above it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.xxxx">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
        <include
          layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The BottomNavigationDrawer is a View, so you may layout it as with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:layout_weight="1""
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that I replaced with a LinearLayout and filled the content_view for the remaining space of the screen.

If you want to use ConstraintLayout (doesnt requires for your layout) the solution would be have a id in the content_view and make it above navigation and below parent